# FixtureException in Grails on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: grails, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded from Sierra to High Sierra, and since then have not been able to run my grails application. I get the following error when running the application. If I disable fixtureLoader.load portion in Bootstrap.groovy, then the application everything runs fine, but then I have no initial data

```
[2018-03-02 10:13:08,751]   ERROR   context.GrailsContextLoader Error 
initializing the application: Failed to evaluate 
requestTemplates.groovy (pattern: 'events/*')
grails.plugin.fixtures.exception.FixtureException: Failed to evaluate requestTemplates.groovy (pattern: 'events/*')
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:986)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1_closure2.doCall(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1_closure2.call(FixtureFileLoader.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1_closure2.call(FixtureFileLoader.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1.doCall(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1.call(FixtureFileLoader.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1.call(FixtureFileLoader.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader.doLoad(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:69)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader.load(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.Fixture.load(Fixture.groovy:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.doLoad(FixtureLoader.groovy:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.FixtureLoader.load(FixtureLoader.groovy:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at BootStrap.developmentBootStrap(BootStrap.groovy:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:960)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:75)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fixture does not have bean 'singleRoomType'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:986)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.bean(FixtureBuilder.groovy:98)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder$bean$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.getProperty(FixtureBuilder.groovy:72)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:169)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:321)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyDelegateFirst(Closure.java:311)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
at requestTemplates$_run_closure1_closure7.doCall(requestTemplates.groovy:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningMethod(BeanBuilder.java:703)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningMethod(FixtureBuilder.groovy)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:561)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(FixtureBuilder.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor494.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.invokeMethod(FixtureBuilder.groovy:121)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1068)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at requestTemplates$_run_closure1.doCall(requestTemplates.groovy:59)
at requestTemplates$_run_closure1.doCall(requestTemplates.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(FixtureBuilder.groovy)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.super$3$beans(FixtureBuilder.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder.beans(FixtureBuilder.groovy:107)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder$beans.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.builder.FixtureBuilder$beans.call(Unknown Source)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.handler.FixtureHandler.doCall(FixtureHandler.groovy:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.handler.FixtureBuildingShellHandler.call(FixtureBuildingShellHandler.groovy)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.handler.FixtureHandler.call(FixtureHandler.groovy)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.handler.FixtureBuildingShellHandler.call(FixtureBuildingShellHandler.groovy)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.handler.FixtureHandler.call(FixtureHandler.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor83.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1132)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1088)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at requestTemplates.run(requestTemplates.groovy:9)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:588)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.shell.FixtureBuildingShell.evaluate(FixtureBuildingShell.groovy)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$evaluate$0.call(Unknown Source)
at grails.plugin.fixtures.files.FixtureFileLoader$_doLoad_closure1_closure2.doCall(FixtureFileLoader.groovy:75)
... 135 more
[2018-03-02 10:13:08,992]   ERROR   hbm2ddl.SchemaExport    schema export unsuccessful
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-173]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:137)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1413)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkClosed(JdbcConnection.java:1388)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.getAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:428)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:421)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:375)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.createStatement(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:239)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.createStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:265)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:229)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:961)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy.close(SessionFactoryProxy.java:180)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.destroy(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:228)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.destroy(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:902)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.destroy(ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:238)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
at org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext$close.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.DevelopmentShutdownHook$_setApplicationContext_closure1.doCall(DevelopmentShutdownHook.groovy:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.DevelopmentShutdownHook$_setApplicationContext_closure1.doCall(DevelopmentShutdownHook.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found out that there are a lot of errors in High Sierra. I could not even run Git after updating but that has been fixed now thanks to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path. I have updated brew but still no success. The application was running fine in Sierra. So, what am I missing? Anything that needs to be updated for High Sierra?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use sdkman to manage your java versions, and use one of those java versions instead of anything that may come with OSX.

Also, delete any cached compiled classes for your project, in ~/.grails or in your project's build directory.